# Can't install PotreeConverter

Tags: cmake, makefile, potree

I installed PotreeConverter in linux, following the instructions of the page of PotreeConverter and this page: [Potree Issue](https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter/issues/180)

So I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties git
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake g++
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
$ sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
$ sudo apt install libtbb-dev
```

For LAStool:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/m-schuetz/LAStools.git
$ cd LAStools/LASzip
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
$ make
```

And for potree converter:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter.git
$ cd PotreeConverter
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLASZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/myuser/LAStools/LASzip/dll -DLASZIP_LIBRARY=/home/myuser/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so ..
$ sudo make && sudo make install
```

However when I did the make install command, I have this error:make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

What happened? How can i solve it? (I'm in the master branch)

Moreover, I just copy PotreeConverter (binary) into /usr/bin, but If i use potree with this binary (the one located in /usr/bin) I have an error.
The command:`PotreeConverter ./DenseCloud9_2.las -o . --generate-page potree_page_2`

The error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot make canonical path: No such file or directory [/home/username/Documents/potreeExamplesNubePuntos/PotreeConverter]
[1]    23691 IOT instruction (core dumped)  PotreeConverter ./DenseCloud9_2.las -o . --generate-page potree_page_2
```

Although the file DenseCloud9_2.las exists.

If I put all the path to the local PotreeConverter (in the build folder of the repo), it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue thread you link is for an obsolete version of the software.  No doubt some of it is still relevant, but you should instead start at the project's actual [build instructions](https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter#getting-started).  I note in particular that for Linux, those instruct you to run `make`, but they *do not* instruct you to run `make install`.  Most likely this means that the build system does not provide for actually installing the software to the system.  You probably will be able to run it from the build tree (once you find the executable), and you may be able to copy that executable to some other, more convenient place.

Comment: Hello! I started following that instaructions but It gaves errors, so I found the other post of how to build it, and it worked.